# AWS Lambda only invoking the first promise function

Tags: node.js, sql-server, amazon-web-services, lambda, async-await

I am trying to bulk insert data into sql server using lambda, the code only inserts the data for the first argument provided for the promise.all , while trying to run the code offline using serverless, everything works fine.

```
module.exports = async (context, event, callback) => {
    let bulkInsert = async (table, db) => {
        return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
            const request = null;
            try {
                console.log("Bulk inserting data")
                const request = await db.request();
                try {
                    var result = await request.bulk(table);
                    console.log(result)
                    resolve(result)
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err)
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Error Occured while inserting data.")
                console.log(err)
                reject(err)
            }
        });
    };
    //Read file from S3
    var file = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
    var buffers = [];

    try {

        //Get the metadata for the object
        let s3Header = await s3.headObject(params)
            .promise()


        let db;
        let insertedTaskID;
        try {
            db = await new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect();
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Connection failed: " + err);
            throw err;
        }


        file.on("data", function (data) {
            buffers.push(data);
        });

        file.on("end", async function () {
            var buffer = Buffer.concat(buffers);
            var workbook = xlsx.parse(buffer);
            console.log("No of sheets in workbook are:", workbook.length);


            console.log("Remaining Execution Time ", context.getRemainingTimeInMillis())

                console.log("Validation Completed ")
                let firstTableData = getData("10002", workbook, "0")
                let secondTableData = getData("10002", workbook, "1")
                let thirdTableData = getData("10002", workbook, "2")
                let fourthTableData = getData("10002", workbook, "3")

                console.log("Inserting rows to DB")
                //Bulk insert the data into respective tables
                try {
                    await Promise.all([
                        bulkInsert(firstTableData, db),
                        bulkInsert(secondTableData, db),
                        bulkInsert(thirdTableData, db),
                        bulkInsert(fourthTableData, db)

                    ]).catch(err => {
                        console.log("Error on Bulk Insertion ")
                        console.log(err)
                    })


                    console.log("Completed Insertion")
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log("Bulk Insert Failed")
                    console.log(err)
                }

            }
        });

        callback(null, "OK");

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        callback(err);
    }
};
```

Here is the lambda logs, the request is ending before inserting to other tables.

```
    08:26:42
    2019-07-06T08:26:42.266Z    da7e5fd0-acf9-48f0-8dfc-5a2ac712f035    INFO    Bulk inserting data

    08:26:42
    2019-07-06T08:26:42.266Z    da7e5fd0-acf9-48f0-8dfc-5a2ac712f035    INFO    Bulk inserting data

    08:26:42
    2019-07-06T08:26:42.287Z    da7e5fd0-acf9-48f0-8dfc-5a2ac712f035    INFO    Bulk inserting data

    08:26:42
    2019-07-06T08:26:42.287Z    da7e5fd0-acf9-48f0-8dfc-5a2ac712f035    INFO    Bulk inserting data

    08:26:42
    2019-07-06T08:26:42.387Z    da7e5fd0-acf9-48f0-8dfc-5a2ac712f035    INFO    { rowsAffected: 3 }
    
    08:26:42
    END RequestId: da7e5fd0-acf9-48f0-8dfc-5a2ac712f035
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda would appear to be exiting before the rest of the bulk inserts have had a chance to finish, you should move your callback call into the `end` event to make sure you only exit the lambda after all the bulk calls have run e.g.

```
file.on('end', async () => {
  ...
  callback(null, 'OK');
});
```

Also, FWIW if your Lambda is `async` then you shouldn't need to wrap `await` calls in that context with `try/catch` blocks, let them throw and the Lambda will handle them for you.

Comment: thanks man , that worked, i was under assumption that after sending the callback the lambda works on background , as i had   context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

Comment: @JithinPariyarath setting that flag to false would would end the lambda as soon as the callback is fired, that's why it's enabled by default.